# If someone is busking on a corner and a drug crazed preacher comes along ranting about gospel in slurred speech is there any offence?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, police, freedom-of-speech

Suppose the preacher cones along and asks the busker how long they'll be there for to which he replies 6pm, when the preacher then says that he'll also leave at six but then goes up to the next junction/block to blast his megaphone/siren, but then gradually creeps back toward the busker's spot encroaching on his sound and space, and also rendering the initial decent interaction pointless and moot, and responds hostile and inflammatorily to polite reasonable requests to respect each other and stay on the other block until 6:00, is there anything the police might do?

Does the needlessly obnoxious and antisocial manner in which they're behaving and clearly drugged intoxication create any kind of charge like disturbing the peace or something like that? Or antisocial behaviour? Many people gathered around the busker to express support and appreciation for him as well as disgust toward the preachers unnecessary disrespect.

Comment: Does the busker have the appropriate license?

Comment: @DaleM yes. He does

Answer (score 6):

> "Does the needlessly obnoxious and antisocial manner in which they're
> behaving and clearly drugged intoxication create any kind of charge
> like disturbing the peace or something like that?"

Probably. But you don't want to take the law into your own hands. Call the police and have them make the judgement. There is a lot of discretion involved; some police officers may simply tell the preacher to move on; others may detain him on public intoxication or being a nuisance, according to local and UK laws, as well as check for permits and licenses for street/public performances.

> Many people gathered around the busker to express support and
> appreciation for him as well as disgust toward the preachers
> unnecessary disrespect.

That's well within rights, as long as the behavior doesn't degrade into the same type(s) that the preacher is exhibiting and possibly be a nuisance or worse (i.s., assault) as per the law.